# Display issue with UISegmentedControl after upgrade to iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol, uiappearance

since the upgrade to iOS 6, I am having display problem with all my UISegmentedControl on which I did some customization. This is how it looks like.

[image: UISegmentedControl]

On iOS 5 there was no problem at all, and if I run in iPhone 4 (iOS 5) simulator it display correct.

This is the code I am using:

```
UIImage *segmentUnselected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segmentedcontrol"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)];
UIImage *segmentSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segmentedcontrol_selected"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected forState:UIControlStateDisabled barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

UIImage *segmentDivider = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmentedcontrol_divider"];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentDivider
                             forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                               rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentDivider
                             forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateDisabled
                               rightSegmentState:UIControlStateDisabled
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The images I am using should be fine, they are in two size normal and @2x. Just tell me if you want me to give some detail about that.

**[UPDATE]**

Removing the cap inset resizable image with a 'normal' imageNamed:@"" solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem:
[Appearance proxy affected by upgrade to iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569300/appearance-proxy-affected-by-upgrade-to-ios-6#comment16935147_12569300)

I've been suggested to remove the divider but still a free blue space is displayed:
[image]

I have two segmented controllers with different heights. It looks like in iOS6 the background image for the button don't get resized correctly,thing that instead happens for the divider. So probably we have to use the same height for all the segmented controllers until they post a fix.

OR

You could create a subclass for each segmented controller with a custom height and apply the images using the appearance proxies on that specific class

Answer (score 0):

Set the Width of each bar in the segmented control, it works for me. But for any ios version other then 6 i specify just the width of the whole segmented control.

This should fix the issue where the divider is large and making the segmented control buttons go out of the frame.

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
if (version >= 6.0) {
    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setWidth:70 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setWidth:70 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
}else{
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 139, 30);
}
```