# Appearance proxy affected by upgrade to iOS 6

Tags: background, ios6, uisegmentedcontrol, uiappearance

My app implements a custom segmented control background image using:

```
// customise the segmented controls
    UIImage *segmentSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)];
    UIImage *segmentUnselected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)];
    UIImage *segmentSelectedUnselected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel-uns.png"];
    UIImage *segUnselectedSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-sel.png"];
    UIImage *segmentUnselectedUnselected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-uns.png"];

    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected forState:UIControlStateDisabled barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentUnselectedUnselected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];    
    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentSelectedUnselected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segUnselectedSelected forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It was perfectly working before I updated to XCode 4.5 and iOS6. Now it's like that:
[image]
as you can see the background images size were altered. Did any anybody have the same problem?
Also some of the background images for some screen look shorter the requested. In one of them for example I have a blank space.

Comment: It seems like the divider images are not longer needed, I was doing some tests and the divider image seemed to be the one that screwed the segmented, don't know why, but try it and it should work ...

Comment: Edit: I found out that my images for the segmented were larger than the actual segmented size, that's why they didn't fit in, just an advice in case you're missing that too, cheers

Comment: I will try it..what about the main view background getting suddenly shorter than on 5.1.1? did it happen to you as well?

Comment: Hmm nope that didn't happen, but could be the same thing as the UISegmentedControl problem, not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you name your images with @2x if they're at that resolution.

I had a similar-looking problem which was fixed when I added that.